# I want to connect react and firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have problem with Firebase and React.
This problem is after click to my add-data button for adding data to database. I get this console.log

> Reference_impl.ts:482 Uncaught TypeError: db._checkNotDeleted is not a function
> at ref (Reference_impl.ts:482:1)
> at insertData (Modal.js:44:1)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
> at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
> at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
> at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
> at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
> at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)

Can you see my misstake. I want to make simple CRUD app.

This is my code.

```
const ModalOverlay = (props) => {
    const sifraRef = useRef();
    const nazivRef = useRef();
    const detaljiRef = useRef();
    const opisRef = useRef();
    const brojObrokaRef = useRef();
    const napomenaRef = useRef();

    const addNewData = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      let data = {
        sifra: sifraRef.current.value,
        naziv: nazivRef.current.value,
        detalji_dijete: detaljiRef.current.value,
        opis: opisRef.current.value,
        broj_obroka: brojObrokaRef.current.value,
        napomena: napomenaRef.current.value
      };
      const uuid = uid();
      set(ref(firestore, `/${uuid}`), {
        data,
        uuid
      })
      close();
    }
```

I watched almost all youtube videos, and I can't solve this problem.

Comment: The `set()` and `ref()` are functions from Firebase Realtime Database SDK and not Firestore. Can you share your complete code including the imports and explain which database are you trying to use?

Comment: These are my imports, firestore is just my name for DB.
import { Fragment, useRef } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import classes from './Modal.module.css';
import { uid } from 'uid'
import { firestore } from "../../../firebase";
import { set, ref } from "@firebase/database"

Comment: You are using Realtime DB SDK. Can you please share a screenshot of your database from Firebase console to show where you are trying to add the data? That'll make it a bit clear.

Comment: I using Firestore Database, probably that is a problem.
Do you maybe have idea how I can make CRUD in this DB type?
https://postimg.cc/GT44nxJM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `'firebase/database'` SDK that is used for [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database). For [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore), you should use `'firebase/firestore'` so that should be:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'

const firebaseConfig = {...} // Firebase web config

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

Then import `db` where required:

```
import { db } from "../../../firebase"
import { addDoc, collection } from 'firebase/firestore' // <-- not firebase/database

const addNewData = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = {...};
                
  await addDoc(collection(db, 'messages'), data)
}
```

This should add a new document in messages collection. Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knk5Fjrpde0) on Firebase channel for more information.

Comment: You helped me a lot.